# how can I make this a word translatable

Tags: template, magento-1, localisation

how can I make this word "**item(s)**" translatable in the below code in line 20

```
        <td style="text-align:center">
            <ul>
                <?php
                $its = $giftbox->getItemCollection();
                $numberitems = 0;
                foreach ($its as $it) {
                    $itemId = $it->getItemId();
                    $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($itemId);
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                    $qty = $it->getQty();
                    $numberitems += $qty;
                    ?>
                    <!--loki-->
                    <?php
                    //$idProduct=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIdProduct();
                    $classname = 'p' . $item->getProductId();
                    ?>
                    <li id="<?php echo $classname; ?>"><a href='<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>' ><?php echo $item->getName(); ?> </a><?php
                        if ($item->getProductId()) {
                            echo ' - ' . intval($qty) . ' item(s)';
                        }
                        ?> </li>
                    <!--end-->
                    <?php
                }
                if (Mage::getStoreConfig('giftwrap/calculation/amount_on_number_items')) {
                    $giftwrapAmount = floatval($numberitems) * (floatval($style->getPrice()) + floatval($giftcard->getPrice()));
                } else {
                    $giftwrapAmount = floatval($style->getPrice()) + floatval($giftcard->getPrice());
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap this word in inline translation function `Mage::helper('core')->__()`

`echo ' - ' . intval($qty) . ' item(s)';`

to

`echo ' - ' . intval($qty) . ' ' . Mage::helper('core')->__('item(s)');`

Comment: thank you very much. In which file I should put the translated word ?

Comment: this did not work I got this error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'core' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/edhel585/public_html/store/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/giftwrap/giftbox.phtml on line 313

Comment: put line `"item(s)","Translated item(s)" ` in `app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv` where `en_US` is your locale

Comment: ive fixed answer, check it out pls

Comment: what about this code

Comment: <?php echo $style->getTitle() . ' - ' . intval($numberitems) . '/' . Mage::getStoreConfig('giftwrap/calculation/maximum_items_wrapall') . ' items'; ?>

Comment: "items"  I tried the same method but did not work

Comment: sorry this actually worked, it did not work at the beginning because in the file I used Item instead of item